# Covering insulation in the garage

Tags: insulation

In my garage, the owners put insulation between the studs to insulate, but didn't cover one of the walls with sheet rock.  It's just a wall of insulation that is starting to fall out.  Can I put plywood or something simple over the area to 1. keep the insulation from falling out 2. allow me to hang small items on the walls?  This is a similar question to one from Jan. 13, and you mentioned Tyvek on the walls.  Is that better?  Thanks!

Comment: Which wall is it?  Is it a wall shared with the rest of the house?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a shared wall between the garage and house it requires something that is fire rated and something that will not allow the passing of fumes from garage.  Easiest and usually cheapest thing to do is to drywall it.  It doesn't have to look good but your seems do have to be mudded - again doesn't have to look good.

For other exterior walls there is no code for the inside of them.  Tyvek is cheap for this and plastic rolls are even cheaper.  But they will probably tear and have issues over time.  If you want something cool and to hang tools I would just put up peg board (if you don't want to drywall.  I will be peg boarding one of my garage walls this summer.

Comment: This is an outside wall, not connected to the house.  Happily the one on the house side is drywalled.  Thanks for the thoughts!!

Comment: Peg board is cheap, cuts easy and already has holes for easy installation.  And every hardware store sells things that hold things in peg board.

Comment: I agree, drywall should definitely be cheaper than plywood.